# Online tex storage

Tags: technical-environment

I have quite a number of tex files on my laptop. Recently my phone went broken and thus all my data are lost. I worry the same might happen to my laptop. So I am wondering is there an online site which specifically used to store tex file?

Comment: google drive, dropbox or any other cloud storage service?

Comment: Just wondering, should I upload everything generated by my MikTex? or I just have to upload the tex file?

Comment: The `.tex`es should be enough.

Comment: This site, if you write "I have a problem with the following file...". (Joking, don't beat me!)

Comment: The whole project folders would be better I guess. Images, external files, fonts... whatever.  You can leave all auxiliary files out, but their size should not be a critical argument. You might want to start using BitBucket or alike which helps you versioning your stuff and has nice syntax highlighting, too.

Comment: The tex file will do just fine, however it really doesn't matter as we dont talk about a lot of memory.

Answer (score 9):

I can't imagine that there are a site specialized in the storage of tex files. However, I know of two sites where you can store the complete project and even edit while offline.

### ShareLatex

My first priority is [ShareLatex.com](https://www.sharelatex.com?r=2e77e739&rm=d&rs=b) that gives you the possibility to sync all your Projects online and backups the complete project to your DropBox account.

Of course, their strongest card isn't the DropBox sync but that you will be able to collaborate with other writers as well (live).

(You will be able to write both online and offline using your own editor)

### WriteLatex

[WriteLatex.com](https://www.writelatex.com/signup?ref=abef72fa3214) is more or less the same but they doesn’t offer you the ability to sync to your DropBox account.

(You will only be able to write online using their editor)

### Online file sharing

You could of course also just use plain file sharing through [OneDrive.com](https://onedrive.live.com/?invref=3cfd82df5ea82dac&invsrc=90) (Microsoft), [Drive](http://www.drive.google.com/) (Google) or [DropBox](http://www.dropbox.com/). My first choice would be OneDrive as the security is higher although DropBox files are easier to share with others.

(You will only be able to write offline using your own editor).

All three solutions has their own client, which automatically will backup your projects.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use github.com to both back up and version control your project. The drawback is that you have to push changes manually.

To solve this problem you can combine Dropbox and github to both version control, collaborate and backup automatically.

Comment: It's worth noting that Github isn't the only place to store Git repos (although it's very good).